# Facebook error "App not setup:still in development mode"

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I know there are quite a few questions already asked in regards to this, but I couldn't find one that answers my current question exactly.

Actually 2 days ago,my app is perfectly running for Facebook login and registration .but now it shows below error .

[image: facebook error]

i have done all the required steps and it was running perfectly.

Comment: check this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960599/unable-to-like-using-facebook-ios-sdk/32044854#32044854

Comment: yes @uma.green bubble is shown with my app name.it perfectly work before two days ago.it is new issue,may be Facebook have changed some thing in iOS sdk

Comment: please login with app created account..if you can login with other account you may display error like this

Comment: @RajeevSharma if its public and still you got error....then may be its bug in fb sdk...make a new appid and start it over once again

Comment: yes it show message on green bubble "Live and available to all user" and i have also tried with new one but still got the same error

Comment: If you're a 100% sure your app is live, I would file a bug on developers.facebook.com/bugs. Also, check that you're not using permissions which require App review, just in case.

Comment: Here your app statue is in Live and  submit your app for review with required permissions.  See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u/54782732#54782732

Answer (score 17):

Logon Facebook Developer Account

on the left sidebar select > App Review > [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwHdm.png)

Comment: I also had to add a PrivacyPolicy before it let me go live

Comment: Without adding privacy policy it wont let you make it live, but even after doing so I get same error with both admin as well as test user.

Answer (score 2):

1.Login in Facebook developer console
2.Go to your facebook app dashboard,
3.near to the top right corner, you can see a toggle button named 'status'
4. switch to Live mode

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u/54782732#54782732

Answer (score 1):

Goto : https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

choose your app from list and click on status than development mode from Off to On (you should must add privacy policy before change development mode) you can also add from here : https://termsfeed.com/